# Get all anchor tags and remove text from href

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, anchor

I have a set of anchor tags being created dynamically here. But on the front end the anchors have an href containing "/usercontrols/" before what I set the href too. Say the href is set to test  On the front end it shows up as www.blah.com/usercontols/test when it should just be www.blah.com/test

```
        foreach (Node child in parentNode.Children)
        {
            if (child.Name.Contains("contact"))
                break;
            var hidden = "";
            var deleted = "0";
            var naviHide = child.GetProperty("umbracoNaviHide");
            var userDeleted = child.GetProperty("userDeleted");
            if (naviHide != null)
            {
                hidden = naviHide.Value;
                if (userDeleted != null)
                    deleted = userDeleted.Value;
               // nav.InnerText += naviHide.Value;

                if (hidden != "1" && deleted !="1")
                {

                    var anchor = new HyperLink();
                    var title= child.GetProperty("title");
                    //anchor.Text=child.Id.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title.Value))
                        anchor.Text = title.Value;
                    else
                    {
                        var name = child.Name.Split('_');
                        anchor.Text = name[1];
                    }

                    if (child.Id == Node.GetCurrent().Id)
                      anchor.CssClass = "current";
                    else
                        anchor.CssClass = "navigation";
                    if (!host.Contains("testcms"))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(child.GetProperty("umbracoUrlAlias").Value))
                            anchor.NavigateUrl = child.GetProperty("umbracoUrlAlias").Value;
                        else
                            anchor.NavigateUrl = child.NiceUrl;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var id = child.Id.ToString();

                        anchor.NavigateUrl = id;
                        //anchor.NavigateUrl=anchor.NavigateUrl.Replace("usercontrols", "");
                    }

                       nav.Controls.Add(anchor);
                }
            }
        }
```

what can I do to make sure that that does not show up in my link? Is there a javascript solution or something I can do in the c# code.

Comment: Does the URL of the page in question contain usercontrols, i.e. `domain/usercontrols/page.aspx`? Relative links will remain within the current "folder" on the webserver. Either change your links to being absolute, or user `href="../test"`

Comment: No it does not contain usercontrols but the folder which this control is located on the server is in usercontrols. So that must be why.